# Switch between IE browser tabs for specific time intervals using script

Tags: vbscript, scripting, browser-automation, ie11-developer-tools

Currently I'm using IE 11, I have 4 displays opened. I want to toggle between the tabs for specific intervals of time. We want this setup for monitoring purpose. I need a script for this task.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly refer the following code :

```
set shellApp = createobject("shell.application")

do 
  for each sTitle in Array("v9", "Google", "Gmail", "ETC")
    ShowIEWindow sTitle, shellApp, 10 ' sec
  next
loop ' forever

sub ShowIEWindow(sTitle, oShell, nWaitsec)
  for each w in oShell.windows
      with w
        if lCase(.LocationName) = lcase(sTitle) and InStr(lCase(.FullName),"iexplore") > 0then
          w.Refresh
          'w.visible = true ' show
          wsh.sleep nWaitsec * 1000 ' milliseconds
         ' w.visible = false ' hide
        end if
      end with
  next
end sub
```

Above code will refresh tabs that specified in the array if they are opened in internet explorer.

Now, instead of Refreshing the window, you need to find method that switches between different tabs.

I also tested the above code and working for me. Hope this will helps !! :)